# Difference Between $\sin^{-1}(x)$ and arcsin(x)

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I am a little confused about the difference between $\sin^{-1}(x)$ and arcsin(x). I know that $\sin(x)$ is simply $\frac{opposite}{hypotenuse}$ and $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is $\frac{hypotenuse}{opposite}$. But then what is arcsin(x). Is it the same thing as $\sin^{-1}(x)$ or is it something different?

Comment: It's the same function, just a different name for it.

Comment: @egglog Did you actually read the question?

Comment: $f^{-1}(x)$ can mean either $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ or the inverse of $f(x)$. $\arcsin(x)$ is the inverse of $\sin$.$\sin^{-1}(x)$ is also usually used to denote the inverse.

Comment: $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is not the multiplicative reciprocal. It is the inverse function [after restriction of sine to a certain interval].

Comment: You should know that $(\sin x)^{-1}$ (i.e. the reciprocal of $\sin$) already has a name: $\operatorname{cosec}$, standing for "cosecant". Also, $(\cos x)^{-1}$ is called $\sec$ for (you guessed it) "secant". There's also $\cot$, the "cotangent" function, which is the reciprocal of $\tan$, i.e. $\cos / \sin$. Note that evaluating a trig function at $\pi/2 - x$ is equivalent to evaluating the "co-" function at $x$, e.g. $\tan(\pi/2 - x) = \cot(x)$.

Comment: Then are cosec and arcsin the same?

Comment: No, no, $\operatorname{cosec} x = \frac{1}{\sin x}$, not $\sin^{-1} x$. I apologise for the notation. I meant $(\sin x)^{-1}$ as $\frac{1}{\sin x}$, not $\sin^{-1} x$ a.k.a $\arcsin x$. My point was supposed to be, there should be no call for raising a trig function to the $-1$, either for reciprocals or for inverse purposes, as all the reciprocals of trig functions have their own names, and the inverses all have the arc- prefix. You can also apply these to hyperbolic trig functions, e.g. $\operatorname{arccoth}$ is the the inverse of the hyperbolic cotangent function.